# Joining two lists of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Given two lists of dictionaries, I want to create a new list of dictionaries where the dictionaries in the new list have a combination of key-value pairs from the original lists.

I'm imagining something like a left join in SQL.

Here is an example of my two lists:

```
DictList1 = [{workbookname: workbook1, groupid: id1, capabilityname: capability1}, 
{workbookname: workbook1, groupid: id1, capabilityname: capability2}
, ...]
DictList2 = [{groupid: id1, groupname: name1}
, {groupid: id2, groupname, name2}
, ...]
NewList = [{workbookname: workbook1, groupname: name1, capabilityname: capability1}
, {workbookname: workbook1, groupname: name1, capabilityname: capability2}
, ...]
```

So

- for each dictionary in `DictList1`,
- I would search through `DictList2` until finding a match on `groupid`.
- Then I would append the groupname key-value pair to that dictionary
- and store it in `NewList`.

Is this something that is possible to do in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this efficiently, you need to first map one of the lists to a dictionary keyed by group id:

```
by_group = {}
for d in DictList2:
    by_group[d['groupid']] = d
```

Now you can produce the output from the second list:

```
combined = [dict(by_group.get(d['groupid'], {}), **d) for d in DictList1]
```

I used a lesser-known trick to combine two dictionaries into a new single dictionary, where `dict()` creates a copy of the dictionary found by `groupid` value, then uses `d` as keyword arguments to update that copy. If you find that to be hard to read, use a separate function:

```
def merge_dicts(*dicts):
    res = {}
    for d in dicts:
        res.update(d)
    return res

combined = [merge_dicts(by_group.get(d['groupid'], {}), d) for d in DictList1]
```

Python 3.5 or newer has a dedicated merging syntax, `{**by_group.get(d['groupid'], {}), **d}`.

All this assumes that `groupid` values in `DictList2` are *unique*, and that you want to create output in `combined` for *every* dictionary in `DictList1`, even if there is no matching `groupid` value in `DictList2`.

Demo:

```
>>> DictList1 = [
...     {'workbookname': 'workbook1', 'groupid': 'id1', 'capabilityname': 'capability1'},
...     {'workbookname': 'workbook1', 'groupid': 'id1', 'capabilityname': 'capability2'},
... ]
>>> DictList2 = [{'groupid': 'id1', 'groupname': 'name1'}, {'groupid': 'id2', 'groupname': 'name2'}]
>>> by_group = {}
>>> for d in DictList2:
...     by_group[d['groupid']] = d
...
>>> def merge_dicts(*dicts):
...     res = {}
...     for d in dicts:
...         res.update(d)
...     return res
...
>>> [merge_dicts(by_group.get(d['groupid'], {}), d) for d in DictList1]
[{'groupname': 'name1', 'workbookname': 'workbook1', 'groupid': 'id1', 'capabilityname': 'capability1'}, {'groupname': 'name1', 'workbookname': 'workbook1', 'groupid': 'id1', 'capabilityname': 'capability2'}]
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(_)
[{'capabilityname': 'capability1',
  'groupid': 'id1',
  'groupname': 'name1',
  'workbookname': 'workbook1'},
 {'capabilityname': 'capability2',
  'groupid': 'id1',
  'groupname': 'name1',
  'workbookname': 'workbook1'}]
```

Comment: I've implemented the separate function, but I'm getting the error TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str at the final line (in my main).

Comment: @JeremyReal: that sees to indicate that `d` is a list object, not a dictionary. Are you sure that you have only dictionaries in `DictList1`?

Comment: I think it may be two lists with a dictionary, like [[{}]], where the outermost list is empty except the inner list. I'm not sure how I did that, but that's probably the issue. I will check it. Thanks!

Comment: That fixed the problem but now I get the error TypeError: 'generator' object has no attribute '__get_item__'

Comment: @JeremyReal: `__getitem__` is used for the `[...]` item access syntax. You still don't have a dictionary, `d['groupid']` is failing.